# Unable to detect a user agent if user is using Internet Explorer 11

Tags: version, internet-explorer-11, user-agent, detection

Working in a company, I am able to detect the user-agent of IE11 when I test on my computer. But when the application (PHP) is deployed, the user agent in IE11 is different and the detection doesn't work anymore.

In local mode, I detect IE11 with:

```
Trident/7.0; rv:11.0
```

In a deployed mode, the user agent is:

```
User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0;)
(also with .NET version within that I don't mention there).
```

Any idea how to detect it properly?

Answer (score 1):

Save yourself some aggravation and don't do this.  The user-agent string for IE has changed multiple times [during the IE11 lifetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx) and can be affected by many factors.

Instead, make sure you're using an HTML5 doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) and then use [feature detection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273397(v=vs.85).aspx), [effective fallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273396(v=vs.85).aspx), and other modern techniques to respond to cases where browsers don't support the features you need.

You didn't mention *why* you need to detect IE11 or what features you were trying to use, so it's hard to provide specific suggestions, however, you might find the following resources helpful:

- [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) (frequent contains a resources tab pointing to suggestions, polyfills, etc.)
- [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) lists polyfills for many HTML5 features.

Hope this helps...

-- Lance